# OpenCV 3.1 OpenCL performance on Nvidia GPU

Tags: performance, opencv, opencl, gpu, nvidia

I am learning OpenCV and one of the first thing I wanted to do was testing GPU utilization using new transparent API which uses OpenCL.
So I ran a sample code with using UMat and the CPU usage decreased by half.
Than I realized it's using my integrated Intel GPU so changed the environment variable OPENCV_OPENCL_DEVICE to :GPU:1 so that it could run on more powerful dedicated nVidia GPU but the result was even worse than using only CPU with Mat and no OpenCL.

Here's my system specifications :

CPU : Intel core-i7 4510U 2.6 - 3.1 GHz

iGPU : Intel HD whith 20 shaders

dGPU : nVidia GeForce 840M with 384 shaders

And the code i ran is :

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
if (!cap.isOpened()) return -1;
UMat frame, edges;
namedWindow("edges", 1);
for (;;)
{
    cap >> frame;
    cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7, 7), 1.5, 1.5);
    Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
    imshow("edges", edges);
    if (waitKey(33) >= 0) break;
}
return 0;
```

When I run the code, CPU and GPU usage is :

No OpneCV : CPU usage 17%

With OpenCV-Intel : CPU usage 5% - GPU usage 9%

With OpenCV-nVidia : CPU usage 38% - GPU usage 9%

I am wondering why the more powerful GPU causes worse results ?

Comment: You are using OpenCL, for NVIDIA GPU, it has to wrap CUDA API, causing deeper API calls than OpenCL for Integrated GPU.

Comment: But it causes even worse result than using only CPU ! @Kh40tiK

Comment: The proxy layer between OpenCL and CUDA does a lot of things like specific API object allocation/conversion, kernel parameter configuration, synchronization ... this is where CPU consumed.

Comment: So are you saying it never has any benefit to use OpenCL on nVidia GPU and the only way to use it properly is to go directly for CUDA ? @Kh40tiK

Comment: No benefit for small scale tasks. To utilize GPU, you have to let it do the heavy lifting.

Comment: So I think i better test it with heavy junk tasks. thanks @Kh40tiK

Comment: You are looking at the wrong comparison too. Work out the frames processed per second and compare those values. You could do this with an integer to count the number of times through the loop and monitor the start and end time to work out how long your program ran. Remember that the CPU has to wait for the GPU so that it can show the processed image, so if the Nvidia GPU finishes sooner, the CPU will be busier because it won't spend as much time waiting for the GPU.

Comment: If you are not 100% sure that you are on the dedicated gpu try to change the environment variable to "NVIDIA:GPU:". After that, change the gaussian blur kernel value to huge value and you will see the difference.

Comment: @chippies You are right. Integrated GPU gives me 25 fps whereas nVidia gives 29 fps. Although, if I limit the frame rate to 15 fps by setting waitKey delay to 66 ms it still uses much more CPU time than when I use Intel. so I think both you and Kh40tiK are right.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi I am sure because I monitor it using GPU-Z. But increasing kernel size showed the difference in frame rate. Thanks.